# NameError: name 'ws' is not defined?

Tags: python, discord, nameerror

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import discord
import openpyxl

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("접속완료했다용!"+ client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='디스코드봇 대화', type=1))



@client.event  
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content.startswith("?learn"):
    global ws
    word = message.content.split(" ")
    word_ = message.content.replace("?learn ", "").replace(word[1], "")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("memory.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    
    

    for i in range(1, 10):           
        if ws["A" + str(i)].value == "." or None:
            ws["A" + str(i)].value = word[1]
            ws["B" + str(i)].value = word_
            await message.channel.send(ws["A1"].value)    
            break
    wb.save("memory.xlsx")

@client.event  
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("?abc"):
   global ws
   word = message.content.split(" ")
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("memory.xlsx")   
   ws = wb.active

for i in range(1, 10):
    if ws["A" + str(i)].value == word[1]:
        await message.channel.send(ws["B" + str(i)].value)
        break
```

I already have  `ws = wb.active` and these are the error down below ↓

> ?[30;1m2022-07-10 19:12:26?[0m ?[31mERROR   ?[0m ?[35mdiscord.client?[0m Ignoring exception in on_message
> ?[31mTraceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\준환\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line
> 456, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "c:\Users\준환\Desktop\봇창고\학습\학습테스트.py", line 46, in on_message
> if ws["A" + str(i)].value == word[1]:
> *NameError: name 'ws' is not defined?[0m*

can anyone possibly help?.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your definition of `ws` is only within some conditional:

```py
if message.content.startswith("?learn"):
    global ws
```

If there is some circumstance when none of the conditions which trigger the the definition of `ws` occur, some other part of the code may try to use `ws` but `ws` has not yet been defined. What happens if you define `ws` outside of the conditionals?

Comment: I see what you mean, but no idea how to fix now. tried many times to put 'ws' anywhere.

Comment: The key is to define it outside of the conditional.

If you do "ws = [thing]" and THEN "if [condition] ws = " it should work

Comment: just tried it and it works, thank you!